# Xamarin Forms - Application.Current.Properties Issue - getting zero instead of value

Tags: forms, xamarin, properties

I'm new at working with Xamarin Forms and the whole mobile platform.  Also, been a while since I've developed anything so.....

I have an app with multiple controls and was putting in the code to save application properties so that they persisted.  All was going good.  All my properties where being saved or at least it seemed like it.  I have 8 radio buttons.  The first 4 values are getting saved just fine.  The issue is on the last 4.

The first code snippet is one working as expected - the value of the selected radio button is being saved into the property correctly.

```
void p1R2PrimaryChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            String newscore;
            String oldscore;
            
            RadioButton button = sender as RadioButton;
            newscore = "0";
            oldscore = "0";
            if (button.IsChecked == false)
            {
                oldscore = button.Text;
                p1PrimaryScore = ToInt32(p1PrimeTotal.Text) - ToInt32(oldscore);
                
            }
            else
            {
                newscore = button.Text;
                p1PrimaryScore = ToInt32(p1PrimeTotal.Text) + ToInt32(newscore);
                Application.Current.Properties["P1R2Score"] = newscore;  //working as it should
               
            }
            if (p1PrimaryScore > 45)
            {
                p1PrimaryScore = 45;
            }
            p1PrimeTotal.Text = p1PrimaryScore.ToString();
            p1Total.Text = (ToInt32(p1PrimeTotal.Text) + ToInt32(p1SecTotal.Text)).ToString();
           // Console.WriteLine(oldscore + " " + newscore);
}
```

This piece of code " Application.Current.Properties["P1R2Score"] = newscore; " works perfectly.

This second code snippet is working correctly. Getting "0" back from the property, yet during debug and stepping through the code it is returning the correct value.  But, if I hard code the value to the property it is returning that.

```
void p2R2PrimaryChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            String newscore;
            String oldscore;
           
            RadioButton button = sender as RadioButton;
            newscore = "0";
            oldscore = "0";
       
            if (button.IsChecked == false)
            {
                oldscore = button.Text;
                p2PrimaryScore = ToInt32(p2PrimeTotal.Text) - ToInt32(oldscore);

            }
            else
            {
                newscore = button.Text;
                p2PrimaryScore = ToInt32(p2PrimeTotal.Text) + ToInt32(newscore);
                Application.Current.Properties["P2R2ScoreA"] = newscore;  // get "0" back on this
                //Application.Current.Properties["P2R2ScoreA"] = "15";    // get "15" back 
            }
            if (p2PrimaryScore > 45)
            {
                p2PrimaryScore = 45;
            }
            p2PrimeTotal.Text = p2PrimaryScore.ToString();
            p2Total.Text = (ToInt32(p2PrimeTotal.Text) + ToInt32(p2SecTotal.Text)).ToString();
}
```

As I mentioned, the variable "newscore" has the correct value in it, to be assigned the property.  Inspecting the property from the immediate window shows that it has the right value in it, but it really doesn't.

Can not figure out why the hard coded value "15" works and the variable doesn't, when it works just fine for 4 other instances.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what does "get 0 back" mean?  Are you saying you assign a value, but later when you try to read back that value it does not match?  Does the behavior change if you call `SavePropertiesAsync()` after you set the property?

Comment: Yes, when I read it back it is zero and doesn't match the value from newscore.  But if I hard code it (i.e. set it to "15") it matches when it comes back.  The other code for the other radio buttons works as expected.

Comment: are you sure you're not accidentally resetting the value somewhere else in your code?

Comment: added Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync(); as a line under my code to save the property and I still get the same result back - different that what is supposed to be saved.

Comment: I've been over the code many times - did a search through all code for the property name because I had the same thought.  I even deleted the pieces of code that were not work and typed them in again while renaming the property just in case I was resetting it someplace.

Comment: if you want to share your project I'll take a quick look, otherwise that's all I can think of that might cause this

Comment: My next step will be to comment out all of the code that sets the other properties and see what happens.

Comment: How do I share it? Got no issues with that./

Comment: post it somewhere I can download it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1l0KJMzPTVtH4rCMUKIJxUXFn3koO2SZZ?usp=sharing

Comment: that is a private share

Comment: Try it now - changed it

Comment: the RadioButton CheckedChanged event is firing when the UI is initially displayed, causing your event handler to Run and reset the value to 0

Comment: Ok, will see what to do to get around that.  The ones that are working also fire at startup.  Thanks!

Comment: the easiest workaround (without rewriting a lot of code) would be to create a bool flag that is set to true when OnAppearing completes.  Then in all your event handlers check that flag and only execute if it is true.

Comment: That is a great idea.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, got it working correctly now!

Comment: @Brettvd If your solved this issue, please post your answer and accept it, it will help others who have similar issue.